# problems importing ttk from tkinter in python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm working with an example file in a tutorial that asks me to first do two imports:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

I get an error. I researched a bit and found that in python 2.7.x I need to capitalize the 't'in tkinter, so I change to:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import ttk.
```

the first line no longer gives and error, but I still get error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name ttk.
```

I have researched this issue on this site and other places, and cannot seem to understand what this ttk is. 
I'm further confused by the fact that, when I go to the python interpreter, and I type "help()", then "modules", and then "ttk" it seems to know what it is, and gives me a lot of description, for example: "DESCRIPTION
    This module provides classes to allow using Tk themed widget set."
-however, python won't let me import it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In python 2.7, ttk is its own package:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
```

This is documented in the official python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#module-ttk

Answer (score 2):

For python version 2.7, to import all packages:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
```

Or you can only import ttk.

```
import ttk
```

For python version 3, to import all packages:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7.16, ttk is its own package:

import Tkinter

import ttk

from Tkinter import *

from ttk import *